# Does the EF Fluent Api can setting the Minimum Length?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, ef-fluent-api

It seems use the Fluent API has more flexibility.

So I choose the way to follow always use the Fluent API to determine the feature it have in db instead use the annotations to.

But here is the problem,I couldn't find the way to set the Minimum length.
Is there a method to perform this?

And i notice,there are no much topic discuss this way.Is the Fluent API way popular??

Hope we choose the right side.

Comment: In must databases, if not all, does not exist minimum length constraint on string columns, so no point to add it to Fluent mapping api.

Comment: I get the point.I was confused with the database's column spec and the POCO property limit.Thanks~ E-Bat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is impossible at the moment with EF. If you really have to set a minimum length, you can do it with an attribute though:

```
[MaxLength(10),MinLength(3)]
public string MyProperty {get; set;}
```

As the first comment under your question already says, it's probably not very common to have minimum length check in databases (never seen it myself), so this will just throw a validation error when you try to enter a value with a length smaller than 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Alex.But I still curious about the affect in database after I append the annotation.

Is it ok in the same time use the annotation and the Fluent API ?

Is the annotation just easy for validate the function parameters ?

Comment: Yes using the annotations and fluent api together isn't bad. I try to do validation of properties as much as possible with annotations because it's clearer to see when you look at your models. The relationships between entities I try to keep as much as possible in fluent api.

Comment: Pardon me, I was reading *maximum*, this answer is indeed correct. The fluent API is not there to validate (although it does that *too*), it's there to configure the DB schema, and there is no "minimum length" allowed in SQL server (which is basically what EF6 supported till EF7), so that's why it's not there. What EF7 will bring in the future is still a mistery :-)

Answer (score 2):

For string property use StringLength

```
[StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5)]
public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I want to know the Fluent API way thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: @Cyrus the question is clearly asking for a solution using Fluent Api. Please read the question carefully before posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late reply for this question still there is no way to specify using Fluent API.

But We can do from Check constraint using Fluent API to make sure Data length is greater than some length.

```
builder.HasCheckConstraint("CHK_DocumentLogo_ExtensionHasAtleastOneChar", "(DATALENGTH([Extension]) > 0)");
```

you need to install the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational** NuGet package to use this extension method.

More info on HasCheckConstraint - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.hascheckconstraint?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).